# ASPxGridView datatable caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I set GridView's source to be result from stored procedure, which is basically datatable.

```
ASPxGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
```

This is happening on button click. On first step it is OK, but when I try to sort, filter or go to next page of results, gridview is empty, and I must click button (to call DataBind obviously) to see results.

So, my question is, how to somehow cache datatable from stored procedure, so I don't need to bind data on every sort or page change.

Thanks.

Comment: Had you checked MSDN? [Caching with DataSource controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227994.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, when you updating the `ASPxGridView` or `WebChartControl` data at runtime, this information isn't cached automatically.

So, you must provide it to the control at every request to the server, using the `Page_Init` event handler.

> To improve performance, you can save data into a `Session/Cache`
>   variable.

For reference check following DevExpress KB regarding your question and KB:
[rebinding gridview at each postback](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q213957.aspx)
[Bind a grid to a DataTable via code.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E168.aspx)
[Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18183.aspx)

**//Cache DataTable in Session to avoid multiple database hit on every postback**

```
 DataTable GetTable() {
            //You can store a DataTable in the session state
            DataTable table = Session["Table"] as DataTable;
            if (table == null) {
                table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
                table.Columns.Add("data", typeof(String));
                for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
                    table.Rows.Add(n, "row" + n.ToString());
                }
                Session["Table"] = table;
            }

            //Otherwise you have to create a DataTable instance on every request:
            //DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            //table.Columns.Add("data", typeof(String));
            //for(int n = 0; n < 100; n++) {
            //    table.Rows.Add(n, "row" + n.ToString());
            //}

            return table;
        }
```

Reference links to improve the performance of DevExpress GridView controls:
[Default grid data binding behavior is unworkable for large data sets](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B148466.aspx)
[ASPxGridView.DataSourceForceStandardPaging Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_DataSourceForceStandardPagingtopic)
[ASPxGridView - How to implement caching using the SqlCacheDependency or SqlDependency classes](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q355850.aspx)
[Best Solution for ASPxGridView with Custom DataTable objects](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/70904.aspx)
[Data caching on the client side](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E123.aspx)
[How To Cache Rows In DevExpress ASP.NET GridView](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2009/09/22/how-to-cache-rows-in-devexpress-asp-net-gridview.aspx)
[Performance issue in GridView when using paging & master detail view](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B148089.aspx)
[Speed up your page loads with a lighter ViewState](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2007/08/16/aspxgridview-advantage-2-lighter-viewstate.aspx)
[Data Loading times and custom record loading](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q132524.aspx)

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: What if my Datatable contains over 5.000 rows? Is it a good pratice to store it at session ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AfterPerformCallback`:

```
protected void gridSchedule_AfterPerformCallback(object sender,
      DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewAfterPerformCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    LoadGrid(gridSchedule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use ViewState**

**Step 1:**

```
 GridView1.DataSource = ds;
 ViewState["itemsetPending"] = ds;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Step 2:**

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataSet m_DataTable = (DataSet)ViewState["itemsetPending"];

    if (m_DataTable != null)
    {
        DataView m_dataview = new DataView(m_DataTable.Tables[0]);

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["m_sort"]) == 0)
        {
            m_dataview.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection.Descending);
            ViewState["m_sort"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            m_dataview.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);
            ViewState["m_sort"] = 0;
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = m_dataview;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here I m Fill the data from Store Procedure into Dataset and assigning into ViewState.Just try it.

```
private string ConvertSortDirectionToSql(SortDirection sortDirection)
{
    string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            newSortDirection = "ASC";
            break;

        case SortDirection.Descending:
            newSortDirection = "DESC";
            break;
    }

    return newSortDirection;
}
```